# How to tell Xcode how to include a library specified with angle brackets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode

I often see open source code importing third-party libraries in Xcode / Objective-C implementation files like this:

```
#import <ThirdPartyLibrary/utilities.h>
```

but when I drag & drop the file structure and files of such a library in my project, all these imports are corrupted and Xcode does not know where the files are.

I end up hand-modifying every import to look like:

```
#import "utilities.h"
```

And include appears it is relative to the current physical folder on the file system. When a library split its files in folders on file system and I drag-drop it in Xcode, Xcode creates groups for the folders. But for import, I have to specify the folder name. Problem is when I am in a folder, for example:

http/httpTools.h

Then when httpTools.h wants to import utilities.h from the root, I have to change

```
#import <ThirdPartyLibrary/utilities.h>
```

to

```
#import "../utilities.h"
```

which is a chore. After doing this for 5 hours I thought damn, there must be a better way. Can someone explain what is the secret to teaching Xcode a new framework location that can be imported with angle brackets? The framework btw is source code. Not compiled. Just the naked code.

Comment: It's not Xcode, it's rather the compiler. Anyway, you have to extend the header file search path of the compiler; this can be done by specifying the `-I<directory>` compiler flag in the case of GCC and Clang.

Comment: I had a similar problem, rather than dragging in the files, include relevant directories in the header search paths xcode setting.

Comment: Are you importing the 3rd party framework or the full source code?

Comment: @H2CO3 how would you specify it for a library called "TheLibrary", and where do you put that compiler flag?

Comment: @openfrog `clang -I/path/to/TheLibrary` etc. And compiler flags are to be put into the invocation of the compiler command line. If you are using Xcode, there's probably a section in the build settings called "include paths" or something like that.

Answer (score 11):

Specify the include path using the compiler flag `-I`, or the Xcode build settings alias [`HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW86). Of course, you can use build variables when doing so.

Comment: not working in my case. It seems xcode only searches from system library for headers specified between brackets.

Comment: You can't just add `include`. Use `$(SRCROOT)/include/` instead.

Comment: HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS did NOT work for me for an unknown reason. Adding -I as a compiler flag worked though.

Comment: @BenjaminPiette that's strange -- perhaps the setting was defined at another level in Xcode's build settings?

Answer (score 7):

Just stumbled upon the same issue, there are two types of search paths in Xcode:

```
Header Search Paths
User Header Search Paths
```

If you add your own include folders into Header Search Paths, you can use angled brackets.