# How to convert c program to fully portable for ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode, openldap

I wrote a simple c program for connect to ldap server using opelLdap c library.
now I want to run that c program on ios device. but when I move that c program to xcode project it says ldap.h is missing. ldap.h file is saved in standard include file location so it include this way `#include <ldap.h>` but I move this file to my xcode project and include it this way `#include "ldap.h"` it generate so many error because this ldap.h header file contain lot of other standard header files and they have their own dependencies and so on. they all are include this way `#include <header.h>` it is not possible to convert all the <> to " " one by one. 
is there any way to to this thing. actually I need to move my code with it's all dependencies 
I am new to both of this c and xcode(swift/objective-c)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877233/using-ldap-for-authentication-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have `#include <something>` work, you could add path to that files into path search list in Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Header Search Paths.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by specifying the `-I<directory>` - it is compile flag or the other option is to set the patch in xcode setting. Third option is to use build variables.

check this out - [How to tell Xcode how to include a library specified with angle brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026207/how-to-tell-xcode-how-to-include-a-library-specified-with-angle-brackets)